# QSort doesn't sort correctly, unless sorting one extra time afterwards

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to add two Priority Queues to each other by overloading the "+" operator.

```
// Overloading add operator (+)
template <class T> PrioQueue<T> operator + (PrioQueue<T> &a, PrioQueue<T> &b) {
    // Create a new queue that's big enough to hold our 2 queues
    PrioQueue<T> newPrioQueue(a.num_items + b.num_items);

    // Push all items to the new queue
    // all items will be sorted on pushtime (get it? Instead of runtime? Haha... Ha...)
    for (T * element = a.bottom_; element < a.bottom_ + a.num_items; element++) {
        newPrioQueue.push(*element);
        std::cout << newPrioQueue;
    }

    // Push all items to the new queue
    // all items will be sorted on pushtime
    for (T * element = b.bottom_; element < b.bottom_ + b.num_items; element++) {
        newPrioQueue.push(*element);
        std::cout << newPrioQueue;
    }

    // This one is needed - why?
    newPrioQueue.sort();

    std::cout << newPrioQueue;

    // New queue is done, return it.
    return newPrioQueue;
}
```

This is my PrioQueue's `push` function:

```
void push(T t) {
    if (!full()) {
        *top_ = t;
        top_++;
        num_items++;

        // Sort items using qsort
        qsort(bottom_, num_items, sizeof(T), compareFunction);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Queue is full" << endl;
    }

};
```

As you can see, the PrioQueue will get sorted after every `push`. However, one last sort is needed after combining the two arrays! Check this output:

```
Queue has 1 item(s): 429
Queue has 2 item(s): 429|123
Queue has 3 item(s): 429|123|24
Queue has 4 item(s): 429|123|24|24
Queue has 5 item(s): 429|123|24|24|3
Queue has 6 item(s): 429|123|24|24|3|2
Queue has 7 item(s): 24|123|24|429|3|2|1
Queue has 7 item(s): 429|123|24|24|3|2|1
```

The second to last line is the bug. It suddenly scrambles all the data!

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here's my CompareFunction:

```
static int compareFunction (const void * a, const void * b) {
    // Relies on overloading of the "<" operator with non-std objects
    return (*(T*)a < *(T*)b);
}
```

This is the input:

```
intQueue1.push(24);
intQueue1.push(429);
intQueue1.push(123);

intQueue2.push(1);
intQueue2.push(2);
intQueue2.push(3);
intQueue2.push(24);

intQueue3 = intQueue1 + intQueue2;
```

Comment: The bug is most likely in your compareFunction, can you provide it as well?

Comment: What are the inputs? What is `compareFunction`? What is `PrioQueue::sort`?

Comment: I've added the requested code!

Comment: @molbdnilo: PrioQueue::sort is a void which just runs `qsort(bottom_, num_items, sizeof(T), compareFunction);`

Comment: `qsort` only works for trivially copyable types, and requires a different form of comparator (returning negative, zero or positive to indicate less than, equal or greater than). You really should be using `std::sort`.

Comment: Before claiming that a library function doesn't work, it's usually a good idea to study how it's supposed to work and what it requires in order to work. Otherwise, you may be making any number of erroneous assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *may* be wrong but your `compareFunction`:

```
static int compareFunction (const void * a, const void * b) {
    // Relies on overloading of the "<" operator with non-std objects
    return (*(T*)a < *(T*)b);
}
```

Is supposed to return 1, 0 or -1 and it return true or false...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `qsort` in C++ without a very good reason. Try

```
std::sort(bottom_, bottom_+num_items);
```

This will compare using `<`, so there's no need to provide a comparator if your type overrides that operator.

If you really want to use `qsort` for some reason, then beware that it only works for trivially copyable types, and needs a different form of comparator, returning a negative, zero or positive value to indicate respectively less than, equal or greater than. You'd need something like

```
T & aa = reinterpret_cast<T&>(a);
T & bb = reinterpret_cast<T&>(b);
if (aa < bb) return -1;
if (bb < aa) return 1;
return 0;
```